# Video Capture (MediaStore) & Upload To FireBase - Android Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Its my first kotlin project and its been 3 months now since I started. I'm making a social app. Now I'm having difficulty in writing the code for recording and uploading video file on Firebase Storage and Database. Below is my code for the Video Post Creation Activity which handles the uploading and publishing. I tried many modifications but the app crashes on this code now whenever I tap on creating a new post or uploading a video. Can you please check what's wrong here. As my intent is only recording a video, and writing food name, place etc and then publishing the post. I'm actually confused on my code.

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.app.ProgressDialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.database.Cursor
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_add_post.*

class AddPostActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var myUrl = ""
    private var videoUri: Uri? = null
    private var storagePostPicRef: StorageReference? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_post)

        storagePostPicRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("Posts Videos")

        save_new_post_btn.setOnClickListener { uploadImage() }

        intent.action = MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE
        startActivityForResult(intent, 101)

        //   var intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
        //   startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_CAPTURE)

    }


    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == 101 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            val result = videoUri
            video_new_post.setVideoURI(videoUri)
        }
    }

    private fun getPath(uri: Uri): String {
        var projectionArray = arrayOf(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)
        var cursor: Cursor? =
            applicationContext.contentResolver.query(uri, projectionArray, null, null, null)
        if (cursor != null) {
            val columnIndex: Int = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            return cursor.getString(columnIndex)
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }

    private fun uploadImage() {
        when {
            videoUri == null -> Toast.makeText(this, "Please select a Video!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()
            TextUtils.isEmpty(name_new_post.text.toString()) -> Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Please fill all the fields!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
            TextUtils.isEmpty(place_new_post.text.toString()) -> Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Please fill all the fields!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
            TextUtils.isEmpty(city_new_post.text.toString()) -> Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Please fill all the fields!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
            TextUtils.isEmpty(state_new_post.text.toString()) -> Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Please fill all the fields!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()

            else -> {

                val progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
                progressDialog.setTitle("Upload Started...")
                progressDialog.setMessage("Great! Please wait until we bake it...")
                progressDialog.show()

                val fileRef =
                    storagePostPicRef!!.child(System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + ".mp4")

                var uploadTask: StorageTask<*>
                uploadTask = fileRef.putFile(videoUri!!)

                uploadTask.continueWithTask(Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>> { task ->

                    if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                        task.exception?.let {
                            throw it
                            progressDialog.dismiss()
                        }
                    }

                    return@Continuation fileRef.downloadUrl

                })

                    .addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener<Uri> { task ->

                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                            val downloadUrl = task.result
                            myUrl = downloadUrl.toString()

                            val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Posts")
                            val postId = ref.push().key

                            val postMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
                            postMap["postid"] = postId!!
                            postMap["foodname"] = name_new_post.text.toString().toLowerCase()
                            postMap["placename"] = place_new_post.text.toString().toLowerCase()
                            postMap["cityname"] = city_new_post.text.toString().toLowerCase()
                            postMap["statename"] = state_new_post.text.toString().toLowerCase()
                            postMap["publisher"] = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
                            postMap["postimage"] = myUrl

                            ref.child(postId).updateChildren(postMap)

                            Toast.makeText(this, "Upload Finished Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show()

                            val intent = Intent(this@AddPostActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                            startActivity(intent)
                            finish()

                            progressDialog.dismiss()

                        } else {
                            progressDialog.dismiss()
                        }

                    })

            }
        }
    }
}
```

So after adjusting my code and restructuring it, this is what I came up with, and its still not opening anything, just closes the app when tried to create a post. It should open up the camera for recording though.

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.database.Cursor
import android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_add_post.*
import java.io.File
import java.io.IOException

class AddPostActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var myUrl = ""
    private var videoUri: Uri? = null
    private var storagePostPicRef: StorageReference? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_post)


        storagePostPicRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("Posts Videos")

        save_new_post_btn.setOnClickListener { uploadImage() }

        dispatchTakeVideoIntent()


    }

    fun createVideoFile(): File {
            val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(java.util.Date())
            val storageDir: File? = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)
            return File.createTempFile(
                "Video_${timeStamp}_", /* prefix */
                ".mp4", /* suffix */
                storageDir /* directory */
            )

        }

    val REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 101
    private fun dispatchTakeVideoIntent() {
        Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE).also { takeVideoIntent ->
    takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
        val videoFile: File? = try {
            createVideoFile()
        } catch (ex: IOException) {

            null
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        videoFile?.also {
             videoUri  = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                this,
                "your_app_id.provider", // add your application id , copy from build.gradle file paste here
                it
            )
            takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri)
            startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
        }
    }
  }
}

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == 101 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("VideoPath", videoUri?.path) // you can see video path in log
            uploadImage()
        }
    }

    private fun uploadImage() {
        when {
            videoUri == null -> Toast.makeText(this, "Please select a Video!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()
            TextUtils.isEmpty(name_new_post.text.toString()) -> Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Please fill all the fields!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
            TextUtils.isEmpty(place_new_post.text.toString()) -> Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Please fill all the fields!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
            TextUtils.isEmpty(city_new_post.text.toString()) -> Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Please fill all the fields!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
            TextUtils.isEmpty(state_new_post.text.toString()) -> Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Please fill all the fields!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()

            else -> {

                val progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
                progressDialog.setTitle("Upload Started...")
                progressDialog.setMessage("Great! Please wait until we bake it...")
                progressDialog.show()

                val fileRef =
                    storagePostPicRef!!.child(System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + ".mp4")



                fileRef.putFile(videoUri!!).addOnSuccessListener {
                    fileRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                        myUrl = it.toString()

                        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Posts")
                        val postId = ref.push().key

                        val postMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
                        postMap["postid"] = postId!!
                        postMap["foodname"] = name_new_post.text.toString().toLowerCase()
                        postMap["placename"] = place_new_post.text.toString().toLowerCase()
                        postMap["cityname"] = city_new_post.text.toString().toLowerCase()
                        postMap["statename"] = state_new_post.text.toString().toLowerCase()
                        postMap["publisher"] = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
                        postMap["postimage"] = myUrl

                        ref.child(postId).setValue(postMap)

                        Toast.makeText(this, "Upload Finished Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()

                        progressDialog.dismiss()
                       /* val intent = Intent(this@AddPostActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                        finish()*/

                        // if you want to return MainActivity just use finish()
                        finish()
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                   progressDialog.dismiss()

            }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We are using getUriForFile(Context, String, File) which returns a
>   content:// URI. For more recent apps targeting Android 7.0 (API level
>   24) and higher, passing a file:// URI across a package boundary causes
>   a FileUriExposedException. Therefore, we now present a more generic
>   way of storing images using a [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider#ProviderDefinition).

We create path file like this:  res/xml/file_paths.xml

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

> Represents files in the root of your app's external storage area.

Add provider in manifest.xml

```
<manifest>
   ...
   <application>
       ...
        <provider
           android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
           android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
           android:exported="false"
           android:grantUriPermissions="true">
           <meta-data
              android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
              android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
    ...
</application>
</manifest>
```

Here's a function that invokes an intent to capture video.

```
val REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 101
private fun dispatchTakeVideoIntent() {
    Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE).also { takeVideoIntent ->
        takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
            val videoFile: File? = try {
                createVideoFile()
            } catch (ex: IOException) {

                null
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            videoFile?.also {
                 videoUri  = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    this,
                    "${your_app_id}.provider",
                    it
                )
                takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri)
                startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example solution in a method that returns a unique file name for a new video using a date-time stamp:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun createVideoFile(): File {
    val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(java.util.Date())
    val storageDir: File? = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)
    return File.createTempFile(
        "Video_${timeStamp}_", /* prefix */
        ".mp4", /* suffix */
        storageDir /* directory */
    )
}
```

Continue if the process is successfully

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Log.d("VideoPath",videoURI?.path) // you can see video path in log
        uploadImage()
    }
}
```

> D/VideoPath:
>   /external_files/Movies/Video_20200510_143935_5711184798783973477.mp4

Finally, we make a change in the image upload function. We need to make this change to get the image download url:

```
if (task.isSuccessful) {

    fileRef.downloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener {
         myUrl = it.toString()

         val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Posts")
         val postId = ref.push().key

         val postMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
         postMap["postid"] = postId!!
         postMap["foodname"] = name_new_post.text.toString().toLowerCase()
         postMap["placename"] = place_new_post.text.toString().toLowerCase()
         postMap["cityname"] = city_new_post.text.toString().toLowerCase()
         postMap["statename"] = state_new_post.text.toString().toLowerCase()
         postMap["publisher"] = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
         postMap["postimage"] = myUrl

         ref.child(postId).updateChildren(postMap)

         Toast.makeText(this, "Upload Finished Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()

         progressDialog.dismiss()
        /* val intent = Intent(this@AddPostActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
         startActivity(intent)
         finish()*/

         // if you want to return MainActivity just use finish()
         finish()

        }
    } else {
        progressDialog.dismiss()
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, I appreciate that. I've applied the changes but still no success. I've updated my code here, you can have a look. It just closes the app. I'm sorry if I did something wrong, I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: I edited your code. You can copy-paste.  Only change your-app-id. I added a comment line there

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've compared your code and understood the difference. Thanks again.